# Boostraping in hierarchical data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
dat <- expand.grid(cat=factor(1:4), lab=factor(1:10))
dat <- cbind(dat, x=runif(18), y=runif(18, 2, 5))
```

where I have observations of 4 cats in 10 labs.

Now I want to simulate samples from this dataset by resampling in order to have:

each cat observed in 5 (random) labs **AND** each lab with 50% (or 2) random cats observed.

Honestly I cannot figure my way out of this... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is generally easiest with a function.

This function takes the data and first filters the number of labs to sample from, then samples the cats for each lab.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- expand.grid(cat=factor(1:4), lab=factor(1:10)) %>% 
        mutate(x = runif(nrow(.)),
               y = runif(nrow(.), 2, 5))

samplr <- function(dat, nlab = 5, ncat = 2){

  dat %>% 
    filter(lab %in% sample(unique(dat$lab), nlab)) %>% 
    group_by(lab) %>% 
    filter(cat %in% sample(unique(dat$cat), ncat))

}

samplr(dat)
```

and you can then change the number of cats or labs being sampled

```
samplr(dat, nlab = 4, ncat = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question was not precise enough.  The desired output is a 20 rows dataframe with **all** "labs" represented and 2 "cats" observed in each lab. And at the same time I want each "cat" to be observed in an equal number (5 in this case) of "lab".  In other word I want to produce a balanced (relatively to the "cat" and "lab" factors) subsample.